# show html tags in html content, show html code snippet in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, textarea, html-entities

I was wondering if there is a way I could apply `htmlentities()` to `var x` so that if I put **<p>hello</p>** into the `text area` and press the button it would display **<p>hello</p>** instead of **hello** using the below code.

Thanks in advance

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText1").value;
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="myText" id="myText1" type="text"></textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction1()">thing</button>
<p><span id="demo1"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<xmp>` tag

```html
<xmp>
  <p>hello</p>
</xmp>
```

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText1").value;
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="myText" id="myText1" type="text"></textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction1()">Show</button>
<p><xmp id="demo1"></xmp></p>
```

Comment: `<xmp>` tag is deprecated so might not work in all browsers. `<pre>` or  `<code>` tag is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is done by replacing the `<` symbol with the "less than" HTML encoding (`&lt;`), and `>` with "greater than" (`&gt;`).

For instance, you should use basic string methods to replace something like

`"<p>hello</p>"`

with

`"&lt;p&gt;hello&lt;/p&gt;"`

(Otherwise, adding it to an element's innerHTML will read it as HTML, including the tags.)

I should point out that you can also try just wrapping everything in the `<pre>` tag, but I've had varying results with it. I think the method above is a safer bet.